Java - How to get Windows network drive full path from drive letter
In Java, I've created a program for internal users to create mappings in our database to locations on our network drives. I'm doing this by getting a java.io.File object from a javax.swing JFileChooser.
The problem is once I have the File object, the Strings returned by getAbsolutePath & getCanonicalPath contain the local drive letter (e.g. N:\myDir\myFile.dat) when I need the full drive path (e.g. \\shared-drive\..\myDir\myFile.dat).
I'd prefer a native Java solution but I'm not opposed to using external libraries as long as I can build from the source.
I tried using the getSystemDisplayName method from javax.swing FileSystemView, it did not seem to return the correct result.

There are a few similar questions such as this but unfortunately the answers say you should start a subprocess and run net use, which is not a nice way of doing it.

JCIFS might be worth looking at

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@k314159 I was able to get your method to produce desired results, however I agree that it's not an ideal way of doing this. Another method I've tried is using sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder which currently works as we are still using Java 8, but I don't believe this would survive if we decided to upgrade our Java version.

I found three different ways of obtaining the UNC file path on Windows from a local file path. These were all tested as successful using Java 8. I'm not particularly satisfied with any of them, but method #3 feels like it's my best option in a Windows ecosystem.
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Mpr;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Winnetwk;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Winnetwk.REMOTE_NAME_INFO;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

import sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder;
import sun.awt.shell.ShellFolderColumnInfo;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(toUNCPath1("Z:\\a1.txt"));
        System.out.println(toUNCPath2("Z:\\a1.txt"));
        System.out.println(toUNCPath3("Z:\\a1.txt"));
    }

    public static String toUNCPath1(String filePath) {
        try {
            File rootDir = new File(filePath);
            do {
                rootDir = rootDir.getParentFile();
            } while (rootDir.getParentFile() != null);
            String drive = rootDir.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "");
            ShellFolder folder = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(rootDir);
            ShellFolderColumnInfo[] cols = folder.getFolderColumns();
            for (int index = 0; index < cols.length; index++) {
                if (cols[index].getTitle().equals("Attributes")) {
                    String unc = (String) folder.getFolderColumnValue(index);
                    return filePath.replace(drive, unc);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String toUNCPath2(String filePath) {
        try {
            File rootDir = new File(filePath);
            do {
                rootDir = rootDir.getParentFile();
            } while (rootDir.getParentFile() != null);
            String drive = rootDir.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "");
            StringBuilder attrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("net", "use", drive);
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            while (true) {
                int nextByte = inputStream.read();
                if (nextByte == -1) {
                    break;
                } else if (nextByte == 13 || nextByte == 10) {
                    attrBuilder.delete(0, attrBuilder.length());
                } else {
                    attrBuilder.append((char) nextByte);
                    if (attrBuilder.toString().equals("Remote name")) {
                        while (true) {
                            nextByte = inputStream.read();
                            if (nextByte == 32) {
                                // pass
                            } else if (nextByte == 13 || nextByte == 10 || nextByte == -1) {
                                break;
                            } else {
                                pathBuilder.append((char) nextByte);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            inputStream.close();
            return filePath.replace(drive, pathBuilder.toString().trim());
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private final static int MPR_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024; // MSDN recommends this as a reasonable size

    public static String toUNCPath3(String filePath) {
        try {
            Memory memory = new Memory(MPR_BUFFER_SIZE);
            IntByReference lpBufferSize = new IntByReference(MPR_BUFFER_SIZE);
            Mpr.INSTANCE.WNetGetUniversalName(filePath, Winnetwk.REMOTE_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, memory, lpBufferSize);
            REMOTE_NAME_INFO remoteNameInfo = new REMOTE_NAME_INFO(memory);
            return remoteNameInfo.lpUniversalName;
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}


You can also use a direct call to Windows API WNetGetUniversalNameW using Java code and Foreign Memory API available from JDK22. This is similar to your method #3 without using JNA:
public static String toUNC(String filePath) {

    try(Arena arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
        MemorySegment lpLocalPath = arena.allocateFrom(filePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);

        MemorySegment lpBuffer     = arena.allocate(JAVA_BYTE, MPR_BUFFER_SIZE);
        MemorySegment lpBufferSize = arena.allocateFrom(Mpr_h.DWORD, MPR_BUFFER_SIZE);

        int rc = Mpr_h.WNetGetUniversalNameW(lpLocalPath, Mpr_h.REMOTE_NAME_INFO_LEVEL(), lpBuffer, lpBufferSize);
        //System.out.println("Size returned "+lpBufferSize.getAtIndex(Mpr_h.DWORD, 0));
        if (rc == Mpr_h.WN_MORE_DATA())
            throw new RuntimeException("Need a larger buffer than "+MPR_BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (rc != Mpr_h.WN_NO_ERROR())
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected result:"+rc);

        // Interpret lpBuffer as REMOTE_NAME_INFO
        MemorySegment remoteNameInfo = REMOTE_NAME_INFOW.reinterpret(lpBuffer, arena, null);
        String name = REMOTE_NAME_INFOW.lpUniversalName(remoteNameInfo).getString(0, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
        System.out.println("toUNC("+filePath+") => "+name);
        return name;
    }
}

However you need to use jextract to generate the code bindings. Use a header file Mpr.h containing:
#include <shlobj_core.h>
#include <winnetwk.h>

Define the set of symbols needed in a file Mpr.sym
--include-typedef DWORD
--include-constant WN_MORE_DATA
--include-constant WN_NO_ERROR
--include-constant WN_SUCCESS
--include-constant WN_WINDOWS_ERROR
--include-struct _REMOTE_NAME_INFOW
--include-typedef REMOTE_NAME_INFOW
--include-struct _UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFOW
--include-typedef UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFOW
--include-function WNetGetUniversalNameW
--include-constant REMOTE_NAME_INFO_LEVEL

Generate the code for the definitions used in Java:
jextract -lMpr -t gen.code.mpr --output generatedsrc @Mpr.sym Mpr.h


Thanks for this, DuncG. We are unfortunately still using Java 8 but I will save this for when we eventually upgrade. Is there a reason this would be preferred over JNA? Cheers!
